# conversion from NSMutableArray of NSData to NSMutableArray of NSString?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdata

my requirement is to convert the NSMutualArray of NSData into NSMutualArray of NSString, Is there any method or function which directly works for above condition, or we have to deal with individual element of each array?

My code:

for (int i = 0; i < [newTutorials count]; i++)
    {
      // mutableArray[i] = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:newTutorials[i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"url: %@: ",newTutorials[i]);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",mutableArray);

Comment: This is not related to Xcode. By the way, a `for-in` loop with a call to `initWithData:encoding:` should not be so hard to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of anyway besides visiting each element, like:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray; // your array of objects
for (int i = 0; i < [mutableArray count]; i++)
    mutableArray[i] = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:mutableArray[i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead of ASCII.

Comment: thanks for response, i used ur suggested code but it terminate saying "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'",

Comment: @rowin does it give you any more information about the exception?

Answer (score -1):

Answer by Firo is correct. Only change required is the syntax used to set/replaced object in NSMutableArray. 
Correct syntax is :

```
[yourMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:
           [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[yourMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Wrong. You can use the `[]` syntax in modern Objective-C to access elements of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.

Comment: [Stuff to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106375/accessing-nsarrays-items-with-subscript)